# Multivariate Normal Distribution. How do we apply this to dataset?

Tags: normal-distribution, multivariate-analysis, binary-data, multivariate-distribution

I am having a hard time understanding the concept of a multivariate normal distribution.

From my understanding, it assumes each group is normally distributed, making one joint normal distribution with a mean of [$\mu_1$ of $x_1$'s distribution, $\mu_2$ of $x_2$'s distribution, ...], and a covariance matrix.

Then, how do we apply this to the dataset? Like I am confused if we have to check each predictor $x$ variable is normally distributed or not to apply this concept. So, if we have a binary $y$ variable of car price over $10,000$, and we also had $x$ variables such as mpg, year, # of cylinders in  the car. Then, are we checking each $x$ variable's normality? Or data belongs to each of group in $y$ variable (Group 1: Car price over $10,000$ / Group 2: Car price below $10,000$) is normally distributed?

Answer (score 3):

##### A Brief Explanation of the MVN Distribution

A multivariate normal (MVN) distribution is simply a mathematical definition of two or more normally distributed variables. For simplicity, we can just focus on the relationship between two variable, such as $f(x_1,x_2)$, as visualized below with weakly associated variables (source for 3D plots [here](https://www.math.hkbu.edu.hk/%7Ehpeng/Math3806/Lecture_note3.pdf)):

[image]

Normally we don't get such idealistically perfect shapes like this in the real world, so here is some simulated data which better represents the shape of truly random data in its 2D and 3D forms:

[image]

[image]

When their association is weak, the shape of a MVN distribution (of just two variables) will usually look like a circle of points on a scatterplot or a rounded hill in 3D form (shown above). When there are two predictors that have a stronger association, the circle becomes more of a flatter oval shape with less data dispersed across the scatterplot, while the 3D hill becomes taller and narrower, as shown below. This is because the mass of both variables "piles up" under the probability density curve of both variables, as it has nowhere else to go.

[image]

[image]

In reality, there is no such thing as an actual perfect MVN distribution, but sometimes it can be close to this and it can lend itself to convenient properties when deriving the mathematics of statistics. Whether or not this is necessary probably depends a lot on what statistical technique you are using. As an example, having a normally distributed $x$ and a binomially distributed $y$ doesn't matter if we are fitting a logistic regression, but would matter if we were fitting a typical ordinary least squares (OLS) regression with a Gaussian error term.

##### Application

Since it seems you are specifically considering this as a regression with a binomially distributed outcome (based off the wording), the predictors nor the outcome need to be normally distributed for a logistic regression which predicts the class (Group 1 or Group 2). In fact, it is mathematically impossible to do so, as the distribution will almost always end up looking something like this:

[image]

So to for your scenario, where I assume you are fitting a logistic regression, there really isn't a need to check this at all. In fact, this is one of the nice properties of the logistic regression, it doesn't really require much in terms of distributional properties other than requiring a binary output. Whether this is necessary for other applications depends highly on what you are doing in statistics.

Comment: Thank you so much!! It helps a lot! I was actually checking LDA. I wondered if I should check each x variable normal distribution then?

Comment: As far as I am aware, it is helpful for the data to be normally distributed *within* classes but not required that the *overall* data is normally distributed (though if the latter is true, it can sometimes function similarly to logistic regression). But I'm not an expert in LDA so take that with a grain of salt. The book *Introduction to Statistical Learning* by James et al. has a specific section on this technique that is very readable and I imagine they talk about this some there.